# How can i execute a stored procedure within current transaction without named query?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

Is there any way to execute a stored procedure in current transaction without `@NamedNativeQueries` annotation? I have already implemented many stored procedure executions using connection object from datasource. On discovering the mistake that they are executing in a different session than the current session I am in, I would like to know if there is any way to execute stored procedure without rewriting it all to `@NamedNativeQueries`?

Comment: TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy might be your friend if you are using Spring. Some documentation in https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.html

Comment: If you do the right thing they should get executed in the "current" transaction. Show us some code, including how you control transactions.